# Problem with MVC ModelMetaData attributes and formatting a Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, data-annotations, modelmetadata

I am trying to figure out how to format a date using MVC3 RC2 and a model decorated with DataAnnotations.

This is my model...

```
public class Model
{
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(@DataFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller...

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( new Model() {DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now});
    }
}
```

This is my view...

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.Model

@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.DateOfBirth)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
```

When I run the site, for both controls, the page displays a textbox with the time included in the string, when all I want is the date (as specified by the decorated property in the model).

I used Brad Wilson's [article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) on ModelMetaData for this pattern.

Is it obvious what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact I believe that the problem here is related to the fact that the `DefaultModelBinder` does not deal with datetimes in a proper way (meaning that we cannot bind a front-end field to a DateTime *partial*, like we used to do in others [*cough*  *CastleMonorail*  *cough*] MVC frameworks).

I've created a custom model binder exactly to deal with that issue. But Scott Hanselman has done something similar [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx), so I guess you can just use his solution.

Of course, you may deal with this situation through attributes, but that means that you'll need to specify that special formatting in *all* DateTime fields. And that will not solve another problem: sometimes we need to have one field for the date part and another for the time part **only in the front-end**, and keep a single datetime field in the backend. This model binder solution allows exactly that.